# Have a dictionary object only hold several items?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have concurrent dictionary to hold some bitmaps, which I've defined as follows (in VB.net):

```
Private m_colImages As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Bitmap)
```

In the class where this is declared I have a function to add an item to this collection as follows:

```
 Public Function AddImageToCache(ByVal lensID As String, ByVal image As Bitmap) As Boolean
    Try
        If (m_colImages.TryAdd(lensID, image)) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unexpected exception: " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

What I need to do is only hold about 4 objects (the most recent additions) in the dictionary.  So, if there are already 4 entries in the collection and another one is added, i want to drop off the oldest one and add the new one to the dictionary.  But I'm not storing a time when added, etc.  So not sure how to do this.  I chose to use a dictionary because of the fast key/value pair lookup.  I have no need to sort it, etc.  So not sure if I should have used a List instead to drop off by index.

[Picture of dictionary flow](https://k7j9lw.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pq-pJ0O3fAdaXoO6lXP8xO85qAx9D5zpQxUhlPJYQEHn73fiiF-ixxhDN-1dOQumAaeGDHUDak3pqv-mbyguaCWeU9cFrqIm8xfhc39xnV-U/flow.jpg?psid=1)

Any help and code snippets would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: You have 4 items and you're afraid that linear search will be too slow? What kind of app are you working on? Are you doing millions lookups per second?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - My concern is that the application is highly multi-threaded doing a substantial amount of things at a time.  I didn't want what I was adding to impact it's performance and also be thread safe.  Perhaps a List would still be ok to use, but thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom solution, limit is set, and the last items are all that are left.

```
Public Class Que : Inherits ConcurrentQueue(Of QueItem)
 Public Overloads Sub Push(item As QueItem)
  If Me.Count = 4 Then
    Me.TryDequeue(Me.ElementAt(Me.Count - 1))
    MyBase.Enqueue(item)
  Else
   MyBase.Enqueue(item)
  End If
 End Sub
End Class

Public Class QueItem
 Public Property Key As String
 Public Property Value As Image
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim q As New Que
For i As Integer = 1 To 8
  q.Push(New QueItem With {.Key = i.ToString, .Value = {new image})
Next
```

Query:

```
Dim query = From qi As QueItem In q
            Where qi.Key = "AB123"
Dim img = query.FirstOrDefault.Value
```

Comment: Considering the OP's question centered on `ConcurrentDictionary`, `ConcurrentQueue` would be a better alternative collection type than `Queue`.

Comment: It's just a simple change from `Queue` to `ConcurrentQueue`, but the difference is critical given the OP's concurrency concerns.

Comment: @OneFineDay - Thank you!  I believe this solution would be fine for this multi-threaded app (since it uses a concurrentqueue.  I've tested out your code and it works great - just one last question.  How can I access the queitem via the key like in a regular collection?  For example, let's say my Key is "A123".  I need to be able to lookup/retrieve the image based on the key value.  If I use something like q.Push(New QueItem With {.Key = lensID, .Value = bm}) where lensID = "AB123" and bm is a bitmap.  How do I get the value via the key?

Comment: Yes you query it with `LINQ` just fine.